# Why might "--enable-load-relative" not work for a ruby install?

Tags: ruby, aix

I need to install ruby at several sites, but the exact location of the install may be slightly different between the various sites.

I configured and compiled using the `-enable-load-relative`.  This seems to work for my linux install but not for aix.  When I configured for linux I used

```
--enable-load-relative --prefix=blah --exec-prefix=blah/linux_code_rel
```

I was able to test the relative loading by doing the following:
first with the install dir named linux_code_rel

```
blah/linux_code_rel/bin/ruby -e " puts 'hello' "
```

then after renaming the directory to linux_code, ran

```
blah/linux_code/bin/ruby -e " puts 'hello' "
```

both times I got back `hello`

When I did the same thing for aix, it does not seem to work.
I configured and installed using

```
 --enable-load-relative --prefix=blah --exec-prefix=blah/aix_code_rel
```

after installing if I run

```
blah/aix_code_rel/bin/ruby -e "puts 'hello' "
```

I get back

```
hello
```

if i rename aix_code_rel to aix_code and run

```
blah/aix_code/bin/ruby -e "puts 'hello' "
```

I get

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

creating a symbolic link using `ln -s aix_code aix_code_rel`, seems to fix this, which indicates that the install is always looking for the code to be found using the path blah/aix_code_rel , despite the fact that i configured with `--enable-load-relative`

I seem to be able to get past this by setting the RUBYLIB env variable, but this seems messy, especially given that the linux install seems to work with the relative loading.

Anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong?  Is there any other why I can set the default LOAD_PATH?  Maybe some post install configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried that option but on AIX that will be some trick to get it to work.

If you find an executable or a shared library (like miniruby or libruby.so.xxxxx) and do:

```
dump -H miniruby
```

you will see output that shows what it depends upon.  Below the "Import File Strings" you will see a list.  The 0th entry is what that particular executable or shared library uses for its "libpath".  You could make those relative paths.  It does work.  But that introduces a security risk (which I just recently was told of) that the Ruby build process tries to avoid.

This is *if* LIBPATH is not set in the environment.  If LIBPATH is set in the environment, then it will use that path in all cases.

Oh... there is actually an exception to this.  (I'm editing as I'm typing)  The 1st through nth entries in the import file strings list can be absolute paths in which case not even LIBPATH will alter the search since there is no search done.

What might work is to wrapper "ruby" in a script that sets LIBPATH and then exec's ruby using the same arguments.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LIBPATH=/blah:/ble/blah:/usr/lib:/lib
exec real-ruby "$@"
```

The small dance that you have to do or worry about is if ruby looks at argv[0] and does different things based upon its name.  I don't think it does.  And the other part is that you might need to set GEM_HOME and some of the other ruby environment variables.

The other real world suggesting is to create a symlink from where it is suppose to be installed to the place that it is installed.  Do this for the bin and lib directory and that might work as well.

Comment: Thanks, wrapper scheme is my backup plan.  using the -x command line argument makes this not so bad since you can set up the environment and then call ruby passing in the same file name and it will skip over all that stuff and start running once it sees #ruby.